# HttpsURLConnection and Cookies

Tags: java, cookies, http-post, httpsurlconnection

Basically i just want to get cookies from server. Here's simple code, but i guess it's not enough to get every cookie like e.g sessionID etc.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

    public class Cookie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            System.out.println(con.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"));

        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
}
```

Result shows that i get only one cookie:

```
NID=61=nNSsAl4g7DfxqHE7t__ghfoCc_J-RmY7PaTNoPOd_khLdvvuqI-fnteHgnQXMzmxj_C5HdMozcGfOTt8PvePLKpbDdUlzdVZiRKwNpQIej6_T69jt9C7Oi6E4F-gWPHD; expires=Mon, 14-Jan-2013 17:16:40 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.pl; HttpOnly
```

Firefox gets NID and PREF, so it's not working.

Is there any way to get PREF cookie?

Can anyone tell me is this proper way(code below) to send POST.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Cookie_Example {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try{
            String https_url = "https://ssl.filmweb.pl/j_login";
            URL url = new URL(https_url);
            String post = "_login_redirect_url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.filmweb.pl%252F&j_username=test.filmweb%40gmail.com&j_password=test.filmweb&_rememberMe=on&pass=zaloguj";

            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Host", "ssl.filmweb.pl");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection","keep-alive");
            con.setRequestProperty("Referer","https://ssl.filmweb.pl/login");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",post.length()+"");
            DataOutput output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream()));
            output.write(post.getBytes());

            Map<String, List<String>> hf = con.getHeaderFields();

            Iterator it = hf.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Result is empty cookie,

```
Set-Cookie = [_artuser_rememberMe=;Path=/;Domain=filmweb.pl;Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT]
```

http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/1134/testgof.jpg

Screen from Tamper Data

It means this code also doesn't work. How Can I get __utma, __utmz etc. cookie?
Can anyone help me? Which books will be helpful?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23865624/1223728)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that with your statement, `con.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie")"` you only retrieve one header. But maybe the server sends you two cookies, in two different headers.

I use another statement for retrieve all headers of cookies:

```
List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
```

To see what you send to server, and what the server sends to you, I recommend use a proxy between your program (or web navigator) and the server. Maybe `Charles proxy` can help you.