# Mobile apps authenticated with cookies

Tags: android, ios, authentication, playframework

I don't have much experience with authentication for mobile apps.

I am using Play framework as backend. Play supports cookie-session authentication, which is great because it keeps the server stateless. Can this mechanism apply to mobile apps (native, no web views) as well?

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for android as I have never developed for ios.

In Android all you have to do is enable Cookies for your `URLConnection`s. 
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10715192/4388512) or search yourself. Questions to this can be easily found as there are a lot.